# Hint word getting cut in android

Tags: android, eclipse, android-edittext

How could i make Hint inside editview to be positioned center without cutoff and i want to make bottom line of editview to be hidden how could i make it,below is my code

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/phnum_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:fontFamily="Font Sans"
        android:text="@string/cell_num_label"
        android:textColor="@color/labelColor"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

 <EditText
android:id="@+id/txt_num"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_centerVertical="true"
 android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/phnum_text"
android:ems="10"
android:hint="Enter Number"
android:textSize="15sp" >

<requestFocus />
</EditText>

</RelativeLayout>
```